# Failed host lookup, No address associated with hostnam

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch data from url api laravel(Laragon) but i am facing this issue.

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'pfe_web.test' (OS Error: No
> address associated with hostname, errno = 7) when i try this final
> http.Response response =  await
> http.get(Uri.parse('http://pfe_web.test/REST/cities'));

Comment: does your url works in browser well?

Comment: yes, it does work fine